# settings.DATABASES is improperly configured (Elasticsearch)

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I am using elasticsearch as database for my Django app. But whenever I run `python manage.py rebuild_index` I come up with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 37, in handle
    call_command('update_index', **options)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 130, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 214, in handle
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 240, in update_backend
    total = qs.count()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 369, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 476, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 457, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 824, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 374, in as_sql
    from_, f_params = self.get_from_clause()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 612, in get_from_clause
    clause_sql, clause_params = self.compile(from_clause)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 353, in compile
    sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/datastructures.py", line 146, in as_sql
    base_sql = compiler.quote_name_unless_alias(self.table_name)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 344, in quote_name_unless_alias
    r = self.connection.ops.quote_name(name)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Spark/ad-tracking-django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/dummy/base.py", line 21, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

The main error is:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

I am also using Haystack for my search engine. My settings.py for Haystack connection is:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch2_backend.Elasticsearch2SearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'haystack',
    },
}
```

Comment: show the DATABASE settings as the error is occurring  there

Comment: I am not understanding the Database section. Should I declare the DATABASE settings or will the HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS play the role of the database connection?? If I have to write the database setting how should I write it to connect my django app with elasticsearch?

Comment: no the haystack connection is different from the database, you need to declare the DATABASE setting in the settings file or else it wont run

Comment: What should I write in the DATABASE setting? I dont want to use any other database except elasticsearch. How to I configure the database for elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
    }
}
```

create a file called `db.sqlite3` where `manage.py` is, and then run what you were running

Comment: won't this then save all the data in the sqlite? I have not understood what actually is going on. Can you please detail this out? If possible please start 'chat' with me

Comment: no, when you are using haystack it will redirect to that, the database is just for making django run properly

Comment: I have a database created so I am using it `'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'core',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'user',
        'HOST': '10.10.105.253',
        'PORT':' ',
    }` I got error `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 11 column 10 (char 274)`

Comment: Please wait a moment. The page is loading very slow

Comment: can you see my new question please. Its is about `RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception')`

Comment: can you please help me in this next question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45428596/search-query-for-django-haystack-app